# IDA Unknown Exception Code 6F4

Tags: ida, debugging, exception

So basically I had set a breakpoint on a WINAPI function call. When I tried to run the program and step over the breakpoint, the program exits with the popup window: `unknown exception code 6F4 (exc.code 6f4, tid 704)`. The function does not return any value as the program exits before that happens, so I can't tell if the function has returned a successful error code or not. What is this exception code, and why did this happen?

Comment: Can you try to set the same breakpoint in x64dbg or in windbg and see if there is the same exception ? Try also to use an hardware breakpoint.

Answer (score 3):

```
\>cdb -c "!error 6f4;q" cdb | awk "/Reading/,/quit/"  
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command '!error 6f4;q'   
**Error code: (Win32) 0x6f4 (1780) - A null reference pointer was passed to the stub.**  
quit:
```